# celery work is not running at set time (specified time)

Tags: python, docker, timezone, docker-compose, celery

1. Problem

   - celery work is not running at set time
2. Situation

   I worked on the CentOS

   First,

   - I started celery work with docker-compose.

     `docker-compose up -d --build`
   - I put the $TZ environment variable setting in the Dockerfile.

     `FROM python:3.4
     ENV TZ=Asia/Seoul
     RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
     ADD requirements.txt .
     RUN pip install -U pip \
     && pip install -r requirements.txt`
   - We also set the time directly in a python file. (Celery.config.timezone Configuration)

     `inst = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
     inst.conf.timezone = 'Asia/Seoul'`
   - However, tasks were not working at the intended time, but were working at different time.

     `'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=4) # Intended working time
     'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=13) # real working time`

The time written on the server log was the time zone you set.
I do not understand celery worker timezone settings.

Please help me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: 'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=13) # real working time 

That time is not exactly exactly the same, probably 12 or 13 o'clock.

Comment: Can you run the `date` command in your container and see what you are getting? I think you may need to link the `/etc/timezone` from host to container

Comment: When I ran the date command in My container, I had exactly the same time at host. 
I will try to lint the `/etc/timezone` from host like you answer. Thank you

Comment: any solution you found?